# Way to recreate material-ui input with variant=outlined using css

Tags: css, react-native, material-ui

Currently I'm trying to recreate material-ui outlined input. As you can see background colour and input is different so my idea to just simply set label position to absolute ant push it up does not work. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

my current css implementation:
[image: my current css implementation]

material design:

[image]

```
  inputStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
  labelStyle: {
    color: colors.black,
    marginBottom: 5,
    top: props.isFocused ? -6 : 12,
    opacity: props.isFocused ? 1 : 0.8,
    left: 6,
    zIndex: 100,
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'inline-block',
    fontSize: props.isFocused ? 12 : 16,
    fontWeight: 400,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
  },
  inputContainerStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    borderColor: handleInputBorder(props.error),
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  containerStyle: {
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingRight: 0,
  },
  rightIcon: props.rightIcon,
```

Comment: please share the HTML code also

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to adjust the label background colour to represent screen background and push it a little bit upwards. Seems that fixes my issue

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like that working with react.js.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is my implementation.

**MaterialInput.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { allColors } from '../../../shared/styles/index';
import './MaterialInput.scss';
import Eye from '../../../shared/images/eye.svg';
import HiddePassword from '../../../shared/images/hiddePassword.svg';



export default function Login() {
    const [labelColor, setLabelColor] = useState('#9d9994');
    const [inputColor, setInputColor] = useState('#d6d6d6');
    const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false);
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inputValue.length && !showButton) return setShowButton(true);
        if (!inputValue.length) setShowButton(false);
    }, [inputValue]);

    const handleInputButton = () => {
        setShowPassword(!showPassword);
    }

    const handleOnFocus = () => {
        setLabelColor('#ff4f00');
        setInputColor('#ff4f00');
    }

    const handleOnBlur = () => {
        setLabelColor(inputValue ? '#696158' : '#9d9994');
        setInputColor('#d6d6d6');
    }

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setInputValue(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
            <>
               <form style={{ paddingTop: '1em' }}>
                  <div style={{ borderColor: inputColor }} className="group">      
                     <input onChange={handleChange} value={inputValue} onFocus={handleOnFocus} onBlur={handleOnBlur} type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'} id="material-input" required/>
                     <label style={{ color: labelColor }} id="material-input-label">Contraseña</label>
                     <button onClick={handleInputButton} style={{ width: '3.3em', outline: 'none',  position: 'relative' }} type="button">
                {showButton && <img src={showPassword ? HiddePassword : Eye} />}
                    </button>
               </div>
           </form>
        </>
        )
      };
```

**MaterialInput.scss**

```
.group { 
  border:2px solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 48px;
  position: relative;
}

input  {
  font-size:14px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  width:300px;
  border:none;
  height: 44px;
  color: #696158;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px; 
  border-radius: 8px;
  &:focus {
    outline:none;
  }
}


label                {
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:15px;
  top:13px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
  background-color: white;
  padding-right: 0.3em;
  padding-left: 0.3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label  {
  top:-7px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

input:required {
    box-shadow:none;
}
```